# jquery ui dateinput alternative field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui dateinput and i am showing the calendar when the user clicks a small  image. In the calendar i have set the selectors to true, so it also shows months and years. What i want, is to pass the chosen date into a textbox as a value.

I did this so far.

```
$("img[id='CalIcon']").data("dateinput").onHide(function(e){
   var dt = $("img[id='CalIcon']").data("dateinput").getValue('dd-mm-yyyy');
   $('#relativeDOB').attr({value:dt});
});
```

The problem is that whatever year or month i am choosing is passing only the current. The day works fine.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: try to put your code on jsbin / jsfiddle so we could help with it...

Comment: Did you try to response "dt" as alert? "attr" function may be source of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, finally i found that one of my colleagues ages ago changed the dateinput core file. That was causing the problem.